# Selenium IDE web driver choose ok on visible confirmation

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium IDE to perform some automation task on a website. I am able to record  my actions and then copy the command and target value and was able to replicate it.

After click on a target, a popup will appear with the option of "Cancel" or "Okay" how can I automate the clicking of "Okay" on the popup alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
```

If it's an alert  all you you have to do is switch to and accept.